# R loops+predict()

Tags: r

Hi I am a beginner with R (beginner programmer in general) and the help documents are absolutely killing me.

Suppose I have a matrix
[a,b,c,d] 
I complete 2 regression of some kind a~b+c+d. My goal is to do a predict() for the variable "a" in test data set but c is full of NAs. How do I replace the NAs in c using the model I have created?

If it helps this is the kind of loop I would do in Octave,

```
 for i:length(c)
    if c(i)=NA  
    c(i)=some_function(b,d);<---- I tried to bold this but it came out wrong
 end
```

Thanks

Comment: You say the help documents are killing you.  Have you tried some of the more targeted introductions to R?  E.g. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf  Read the chapters on linear models and on data.frames and that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will have a read in a few hours. Yea the help documents are killing me :S. I usually jump straight into help docs but the R docs are pretty hard to read/understand compared other softwares.

I think I understand the basics of control statement but the bolded part in my octave code ,c(i)=some_function(b,d), is what is really giving me a headache. Could you perhaps just suggest something I can type into google? Thanks

Comment: Try square brackets to subset a vector: if `c <- 1:10` then `c[3]` gives you 3 and `c[3] <- some_function()` assigns the results of the call to some_function() to the third element of `c`.

Comment: To be honest the wording of statement1,2,3, etc section of the R intro documents was what lost me. It will probably become clearer if I read the earlier sections haha. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

It's even easier than Seb suggests.

```
c[is.na(c)] <- mean(c, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Here, the mean function returns a single number (namely the mean of all the values in `c` that weren't `NA`).  The assignment operator `<-` then assigns this number to every element in `c` where `is.na` returns `TRUE`.

---

As an alternative, try passing the argument `na.action = na.omit` to the predict function.

---

The direct translation of your Octave script is something like

```
for(i in seq_along(c))
{
  if(is.na(c[i]))
  {  
    c(i) <- some_function(b[i], d[i])
  }
}
```

Note however that in R, just as in Octave, loops are usually inferior to operating directly on vectors.

Comment: wow no wonder why I was stuck... was looking for something like find in matlab but it is already built in. Thanks

Comment: @Pk.yd: The R equivalent of MATLAB's `find` function is `which`.  Also, coincidentally, the R equivalent of MATLAB's `which` function is `find`.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like

```
c <- ifelse(is.na(c), mean(c, na.rm=TRUE), c)
```

you may want to check the help files `?ifelse` and `?is.na`.

Comment: Wow I will test that out soon! Just a few questions,
Why doesn't that code replace the na with the entire c matrix, is this just how R works?
Can I use predict() instead of mean() without hassle?

Comment: sure you can use `predict()` instead. e.g. `c <- ifelse(is.na(c), predict(fit), c)`. The statement does not replace the whole vector since the first argument supplied restricts it.